# Encrypted sparse bundle disk image visible in the cloud?

Tags: encryption, sparsebundle

I have an encrypted sparse bundle disk image that I synchronize with Google Drive. When I mount this image on my local machine, is it's content also visible in the cloud (decrypted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is only mounted locally. No one would be able to see it unless they can also see your computer.